# How to pass a QVector as an optional argument to a function in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, qtquick2

Function declaration:

```
Q_INVOKABLE void formPackets (unsigned char          argPacketDescriptor,
                              unsigned char          argNoOfBytes,
                              QVector<unsigned char> argBody);
```

**Third argument `QVector` should be optional.**

I know that one way is to specify a default argument for `QVector`, but I don't know how to do that with a "QVector" or a "QList".

How to pass a `QVector` as an optional argument to a function in c++?

Comment: Maybe `QVector<unsigned char> argBody = QVector<unsigned char>()`?

Comment: Use a default argument with an empty vector? Overloads so you have two functions, one taking a vector and another that don't? It all depends on what you are going to do if the "optional" argument is not passed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use default argument, you need to provide the default value to use, when argument is missing. So simply this should work:

```
Q_INVOKABLE void formPackets (unsigned char          argPacketDescriptor,
                              unsigned char          argNoOfBytes,
                              QVector<unsigned char> argBody = QVector<unsigned char>());
```

For reference, here's [doc link to `QVector` default constructor](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#QVector).

---

Above assumes, you don't need "no vector given" and "empty vector given" to mean different things. If you do need them to mean different things, then you need to provide separate overloads:

```
Q_INVOKABLE void formPackets (unsigned char          argPacketDescriptor,
                              unsigned char          argNoOfBytes,
                              QVector<unsigned char> argBody);

Q_INVOKABLE void formPackets (unsigned char          argPacketDescriptor,
                              unsigned char          argNoOfBytes);
```

---

Third Qt way would be to pass the 3rd argument as [`QVariant`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html). Then you could have [null `QVariant`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#isNull) mean no argument, and a `QVector`, empty or not, mean that argument exists. Function declaration:

```
Q_INVOKABLE void formPackets (unsigned char  argPacketDescriptor,
                              unsigned char  argNoOfBytes,
                              QVariant       argBody);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. Make two separate overloads.
2. Specify a default argument.

I would prefer the first in most cases -- it is less likely to lead to trouble.

Comment: i know that we have to specify a default argument, but i don't know how to do that with a "vector" or a "list".